# Spark: transform dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I work with Spark 1.6.1 in Scala.

I have one dataframe, and I want to create different dataframe and **only want to read 1 time**.

For example one dataframe have two columns **ID and TYPE**, and I want to create **two dataframe**  one with the **value of type = A** and other with **type value = B**.

I've checked another posts on stackoverflow, but found only the option to read the dataframe 2 times.
However, I would like another solution with the best performance possible.

Kinds regards.

Comment: what do you mean by read 1 time?

Answer (score -1):

Spark will read from the data source multiple times if you perform multiple actions on the data. The way to aviod this is to use `cache()`. In this way, the data will be saved to memory after the first action, which will make subsequent actions using the data faster.

Your two dataframes can be created in this way, requiring only one read of the data source.

```
val df = spark.read.csv(path).cache()

val dfA = df.filter($"TYPE" === "A").drop("TYPE")
val dfB = df.filter($"TYPE" === "B").drop("TYPE")
```

The "TYPE" column is dropped as it should be unnecessary after the separation.

Comment: Is It not possible read one time and redirect directly the row for the specifik dataframe. Like using foreach and insert the row in the corresponding dataframe.

Comment: @BiCCThor That is most probably not as efficient as this approach. It would require using `map` and build up the dataframe yourself, Spark will not be able to optimize such an operation.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was wondering if the best approach is to cache the dataframe and read it n times.   know is not the most efficent, but is it the most efficent, create one cache with this dataframe and read n times for each type that you want to split.

Comment: @BiCCThor As the dataframe is cached there will only be one read, which is as efficient  as it gets. Anlternative would be to not split it at all and use different `groupBy` methods and aggregate functions to get the result you want.